# How to convert a string to a valid DateTime

Tags: vb.net

Need to convert this string:
Mon Oct 31 16:18:15 CDT 2011

Into a valid DateTime value.
Have tried every variation of the [date time styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.GLOBALIZATION.DATETIMESTYLES.NOCURRENTDATEDEFAULT%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V3.5%22%29;k%28DevLang-VB%29&rd=true) with DateTime.Parseto no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you concerned with converting between time zones or are you assuming the timezone in the string is the local one?

Comment: Actually just want to extract a valid date / time and ignore the Day and time zone as this will be useds as a timestamp.

Comment: Is the timezone always CDT? Or will this change? I understand that you want this ignored?

Comment: will always be central US time, could be daylight or standard

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961848/how-to-use-timezoneinfo-to-get-local-time-during-daylight-savings-time

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the `CDT` you have there. This is **not** a valid portion of a string representing a `DateTime`.

You may have luck with replacing this with a valid representation of a timezone `-0500` and the `K` format specifier for it.

---

You can use the following format string to parse the string:

```
ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss CDT yyyy
```

For instance:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("Mon Oct 31 16:18:15 CDT 2011", 
                    "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss CDT yyyy", 
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I suggest reading the documentation for [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Yeah you will have to replace that CDT with the offset as Oded has said.

Comment: Thanks - I will read.  That ParseExact handled the CDT just fine.

Comment: @user569963 - Note that `ParseExact` will throw an exception if not successful. There is a `TryParseExact` that will not throw an exception but return a boolean value indicating success or failure.