# how to get current UTC offset of different timezones?

Tags: c#, datetime

Problem:
I Need to execute a task on a server that is on UTC at specific time in different time zones. Say for example I want to execute at 9:00AM Pacific Time, irrespective of Daylight Savings changes.

What do I have?
I checked the enumeration of time zones by doing

```
var infos = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
foreach (var info in infos)
{
    Console.WriteLine(info.Id);
}
```

I could see only "Pacific Standard Time" for the pacific time for example and If I do the following,

```
TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time").GetUtcOffset(DateTime.UtcNow)
```

I get `-07:00:00` as output but as of now the offset is -08. That means it doesn't consider the daylight changes.

I was planing to to create a DateTime instance based on the offset I get above, which doesn't seem to work as I expected.

Also, I can't use frameworks like [NodaTime](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/)

Any idea how I can get it working?

Comment: Look at [this SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961848/how-to-use-timezoneinfo-to-get-local-time-during-daylight-savings-time)

Comment: At the moment I believe Pacific Time *is* UTC-7. It's UTC-8 during Standard Time, but we're on Daylight Saving Time at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
var chinaTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("China Standard Time"));
var pacificTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time"));
```

The string passed to `FindSystemTimeZoneById` is picked form `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()`

Update: cleansed the code

Answer (score 6):

You've already got your answer, using `TimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset` and passing a `DateTime` with `DateTimeKind.Utc` will work.

> I get -07:00:00 as output but as of now the offset is -08. That means it doesn't consider the daylight changes.

Actually, -7 is indeed the current offset, as Pacific time is currently using daylight saving time.  In the winter, the offset reverts to -8, which is the standard offset.  I think you just have them backwards.

Also, keep in mind that the `Id` property of a `TimeZoneInfo` object is the identifier for the entire time zone.  Some of them are misleading, like `"Pacific Standard Time"` - which would make you believe that it only uses Pacific Standard Time (PST), but actually it represents the entire North American Pacific Time zone - including Pacific Standard Time *and* Pacific Daylight Time.  It will switch offsets accordingly at the appropriate transitions.