# Why does the code below return 4:14 PM instead of 3:14 PM?

Tags: utc

I'm trying to convert a UTC to a CST by using the 'ConvertTimeFromUtc' method.  However, the result is off by 1 hour compared to what I got when I try to convert it manually online.

```
StatusDatetime is 2017-06-05 21:14:39.6216795  
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(StatusDatetime.Value, 
TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time")).ToString("hh:mm 
tt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Central Daylight Time instead of Central Standard Time, as we are in daylight savings time.

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting the error below when I try what you suggested : The time zone ID 'Central Daylight Time' was not found on the local computer.

Comment: Ah, that is because i was wrong, check out the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961848/how-to-use-timezoneinfo-to-get-local-time-during-daylight-savings-time  its in c#, but i don't see it being much different via java