# How to use TimeZoneInfo Class with daylight savings To CONVERT TO UTC

Tags: c#, .net, timezone

I am using the TimeZoneInfo class to convert a Datetime value to UTC. However, the conversion does not take care of Daylight Savings Time automatically. How can I achieve that.

For instance, I am trying to convert the following DateTime to UTC:

```
//meetingDate is "10/04/2019 12:00:00" PM

var timeZoneId="AUS Eastern Standard Time";

DateTime dtUTC = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(meetingDate, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneId), TimeZoneInfo.Utc);
```

the value returned is: 10/04/2019 02:00:00 UTC (am)

And this is because the Time zone in my operative system for "AUS Eastern Standard Time" is UTC + 10:00  (See image below)
But because the "Adjust for daylight saving time Automatically" Setting is enabled , I am able to see the right time on my windows 10 (which is actually at this specific moment (1st April 2019) UTC + 11)

How can i get the same behaviour using TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime method.

That if i pass the value "10/04/2019 12:00:00 PM" I should get back: 10/04/2019 01:00:00 am UTC

P.S: I have checked out the following stack overflow question but it is converting from UTC, So it does not apply to my question.

[How to use TimeZoneInfo to get local time during Daylight Savings Time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961848/how-to-use-timezoneinfo-to-get-local-time-during-daylight-savings-time)

Image Windows 10 Timezone:

[image: Image Windows 10 Timezone]

Comment: Duplicate where?

Comment: @Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani don't see any question that relate to what i am specifically looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is already doing the right thing and adjusting for daylight savings. "AUS Eastern Standard Time" is the Windows equivalent of the IANA Australia/Sydney zone. The transitions for Australia/Sydney are [shown in my Noda Time site](https://nodatime.org/tzvalidate/generate?zone=Australia/Sydney), and they indicate that there's a transition on April 6th 4pm UTC (so April 7th 3am local time) from UTC+11 to UTC+10.

That means by April 10th - the date of the local time you're *asking* to be converted - the offset is indeed UTC+10, and 10/04/2019 02:00:00 UTC (am) is the correct result. If it gave a result of 1am (so subtracting a UTC offset of +11) that would be incorrect because that *wouldn't* be adjusting from the daylight saving transition on April 6th.

Comment: Just to validate Jon's answer, [here is timeanddate.com's converter, showing the conversion for this local time to UTC](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20191004T020000&p1=240&p2=1440).